# Why is the subclass method definition used?

Tags: java, class, casting

```
Undergraduate ug = new Undergraduate (“Sam”, 999, 1);
Person p = (Person) ug // Type casting
p.writeOutput();
```

`Undergraduate` is the child class of `Person`. Undergraduate's method `writeOutput` overrides that in `Person`. Why is the `writeOutput` of the `Undergraduate` invoked, though variable `p` references the object of type `Person`?

Comment: Polymorphism. The runtime type is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what polymorphism is. From the official [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html):

> The Java virtual machine (JVM) calls the appropriate method for the object that is referred to in each variable. It does not call the method that is defined by the variable's type. This behavior is referred to as *virtual method invocation* and demonstrates an aspect of the important polymorphism features in the Java language.

Answer (score 0):

Java is nice there and invokes undergraduate.writeoutput. You can not invoke persons method except from undergraduate via super.